# Hanging temporary doors and then replacing

Tags: doors

We are in the approaching the end of finishing our basement with a GC. The wife has decided that she must have some fancy interior doors with windows that of course are a custom order and will take over a month to get. Everything is a standard size and it is really just the arrangement of the panels and glass that make them *fancy*.

Is it a mistake to buy and hang cheap slabs as a temporary measure and then install the fancy doors (they are slabs also) when they come in? For *new construction* how hard/long is it to replace a door slab?

The plan is to move into the basement while we work on the upstairs, so we need the temporary doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order cheap slab doors and the fancy doors from the same supplier, then swapping the old for the new should be extremely easy and not prohibitively expensive.

Though it might seem like you're burning money, ordering both cheap and fancy as pre-hung units *should* mean that it's just a couple of hinge pins, a doorknob move, and you'll be swapped. The door casing isn't a major part of the price of a prehung door.

** caveat on the "should" is that hinge spacing might vary and it then becomes a bit more carpentry to fix it... but if you inform your supplier in advance of the plan, you've got better odds of success.